# Does SonarQube have client libraries for web api with classes to store JSON?

Tags: java, json, sonarqube

First timer here and just starting with (the latest) SonarQube. Are there client libraries to download through the web-api already written and available? And is there a set of JAVA classes established that map to the structure of the JSON that will be returned that already exist? I was able to write my own test JAVA code to connect and to parse using the web api provided for one call I wanted, by building my own classes. But it seems like a lot of work to do this for all the data I hoped to pull and wondered if someone had done it already and/or Sonar provided it. And the web-api is a bit cryptic. Had to hover over values to figure out the exact call. I didn't see what I was looking for in the documentation or here. Or is there a better way to dump the data efficiently out of the GUI? Thank you!

Comment: Using the API is the best way although you could query the database you use. The API is cryptic indeed; especially the login part.

Comment: Querying the database is really a bad idea, there are no guarantees about schema stability and you can corrupt your SQ instance

Answer (score 0):

Concerning, JAVA client library to request the SonarQube web services, we do not provide such library. There are lot of great tools to do a HTTP request and parse the JSON (see for instance [OkHTTP](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) and [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson)).

Concerning "the web-api is a bit cryptic", I would be very interested to hear all your feedbacks about this, please share these feedbacks on the [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sonarqube) in order to discuss them and improve SonarQube web services.

Comment: The example would be: I hover over the page and the tech debt ratio URL says: /sonar/component_measures?id=xxx&metric=sqale_debt_ratio. But the api call I have to make is: /api/measures/component?component=xxx&metricKeys=sqale_debt_ratio. How would I know that if someone didn't tell me? And how about Critical or Blocker severity count? I can't figure that one out. The hover link says: /project/issues?id=xxx&resolved=false&severities=CRITICAL, but I'm not sure what I should use in my code to get there! Thanks very much! (sorry, didn't go to google yet, will try to check out tonight)

Comment: Oh, I think I see where it is now, it's "issues/search". Sorry, first time doing this. I